# Que quiere decir OS en pytho?

Tags: python

-La pregunta es bastante sencilla: que quiere decir el nombre del modulo OS, ya que, obviamente es un acronimo de alguna otra cosa...

Comment: Operating System. Contiene funciones particulares al sistema operativo.

Comment: Ya te dieron la respuesta, pero ¿Que es lo que investigastes? En internet al poner solo "modulo O.S", te dice que significa. Con lo anterior dicho, te recomiendo leer lo siguiente: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884

Comment: @JuanRivera Si, lo que investigue esta en esta pregunta, me parece mucho mas rapido simplemente poner la pregunta aqui en vez de arriegarme a perder mas tiempo buscando por internet, algo que ya me ha pasado varias veces.

Comment: @JuanRivera Buscar esas palabras clave en Google arroja resultados sobre el proposito del modulo os. Pero ninguno de esos resultados dice de manera directa el significado del acronimo (que es lo que pregunta OP)

Comment: @JuanRivera ya encontre un resultado que hace lo que dices. Recuera que "os" es un acronimo en ingles, por lo que no queda tan claro. Aun asi puede ser que con algo de investigación OP haya encontrado la respuesta. Sospecho que la pregunta es más por curiosidad que por otra cosa.

Comment: @JuanRivera Independienmente de la velocidad a la que aparezca o el esfuerzo que me suponga (en cualquier caso, tal como dice Dante, tampoco me aparecen resultados) el hecho es que la pregunta fue respondida con exito, si con tus comentarios no piensas aportar en algo, por favor, te sugiero que no los hagas.

Comment: @DanteS. efectivamente, simplemente me dio curiosidad, parece que las consultas por curiosidad no son bien recibidas en este foro

Comment: @JuanRivera entiendo, tiene sentido

Comment: @user215297 No es que las preguntas por curiosidad sean mal recibidas, sino que la comunidad piensa que no te haz esforzado en investigar tu mismo antes de preguntar en el foro. Y eso es lo que se espera como haz visto en el link que Juan te pasó. Además, por lo que veo, tu pregunta fue percibida como "basada en opiniones", lo cual si no es bien recibido.

Answer (score 2):

Singifica "Operating System." Estos son todos los modulos relacionados a interacciones con el sistema operativo

Comment: Mejor no responder preguntas basadas en opiniones. Estas terminan generalmente cerradas.

Answer (score 0):

Es una librería que referencia a Operative System, en este módulo puedes encontrar funciones que gestionan directorios, que gestionan permisos, funciones para crear enlaces simbólicos etc